# Android: CameraSourcePreview doesn't fill whole screen height

Tags: android, google-play-services, vision

I am using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'`

for QR code And EAT-8, EAT-13 and others.

but i am not able to manage size of

```
<com.testing.CameraSourcePreview
                android:id="@+id/preview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.testing.GraphicOverlay
                    android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </com.testing.CameraSourcePreview>
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution for above question is:

Comment or remove below lines from CameraSourcePreview and it should be fine. I was having same issue like you and it is solved now.

```
if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
childHeight = layoutHeight;
childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

check out this library...this is also work on google play service.
you can get full screen Scanner or whatever size you want.

https://github.com/nisrulz/qreader

Answer (score 0):

```
private ViewGroup.LayoutParams paramsNotFullscreen; //if you're using RelativeLatout           

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) //To fullscreen
{
    paramsNotFullscreen=(ViewGroup.LayoutParams) CameraSourcePreview.getLayoutParams();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(paramsNotFullscreen);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    params.height=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.width=ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    CameraSourcePreview.setLayoutParams(params);

} 
else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
{
    CameraSourcePreview.setLayoutParams(paramsNotFullscreen);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
       int width = 320;
       int height = 240;
       if (mCameraSource != null) {
         Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
         if (size != null) {
          width = size.getWidth();
          height = size.getHeight();
         }
       }
/* 
Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees 
*/

        if (isPortraitMode()) {
            int tmp = width;
            width = height;
            height = tmp;
        }

        final int layoutWidth = right - left;
        final int layoutHeight = bottom - top;

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
            getChildAt(i).layout(0, 0, layoutWidth, layoutHeight);
        }

        try {
            startIfReady();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
        }
    }
```

---

> ******** Also do not forget to comment this line:***

---

```
mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context, myFaceDetector)
// .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480). This line need to be commented or deleted
.setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
.setRequestedFps(15.0f)
.build();
```

---

> Here is the right answer, which is working on portrait mode, I did't
>   check it on landscape mode, but it should work, because I am setting
>   the layout width and height according to the screen sizes.

---